# Is there a way to use Knex to have a column of arrays?

Tags: backend, knex.js

```
{
  "id": "_9y0eqwalx",
  "tags": [
    "test",
    "python",
    "sheets"
  ],
  "title": "Whats your plans?",
  "textBody": "  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "__v": 1,
  "time": "2018-08-23T20:24:45.294Z",
  "length": 2306,
  "index": 4
},
```

So I need the data to look like this for each note. The issue comes with the "tags" where it will not let me post an array. I tried to do the following.

```
  exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('notes', function(tbl){
    tbl.string("id").notNullable()
    tbl.string('title').notNullable()
    tbl.string('textBody').notNullable()
    tbl.integer('__v').defaultTo(0)
    tbl.integer("length")
    tbl.string("time")
    tbl.enu('tags',[]).notNullable()
  })
};
```

However the "tags" column always results to null. How can I set up the knex table to accept an array?

Comment: As an alternative, I have decided to use a string format for the 'tags' column and inserted the data as a comma split string. This way I can convert it to an array on the front end. Though I am still curious as to how tbl.enu works and if it is possible to have a column of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To give better answer I would actually need to know which database engine are you using.

There is no any other database agnostic way to store an array except for storing it as a serialized string. Couple of easy serialization choices would be `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` or `string.split(',')` and `string.join(',')`. Anyways that requires manual conversion every time you write / read those enum arrays.

To create a real array column in knex you need to use `.specificType()` and give raw column type to database. Or you can use for example `.jsonb()` type on postgresql and store data as json array.

Knex does not have much support for working with json types so you might be better off by using Objection.js on top of knex (it has support for many postgresql json operations).

Comment: I am using sqlite3

Comment: sqlite doesn't even have array column type so you need to use string to store it